# Rounding up a cell value to the next multiple of 10 (not just nearest 10)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop, excel-2007

I am using a Formula Array in cells H2 and H3 in Sheet2 (say) but using VBA coding.
What I need to do with these values is round them both up to the next multiple of 10. I do not want them just to round up/down to the nearest 10. Also, the value in H3 is a negative so technically 'rounding down' to the next negative multiple of 10 (if that makes sense).

Ie. If H2 = 73 then I want this to be rounded up to 80 and this value held in cell I2
    If H3 = -54 then I want this to be rounded to -60 and this value held in cell I3 (supposedly this might mean timing -54 by -1 then rounding up and then timing the 60 by -1 again) not entirely sure if its easier the way I first described.

Anyway, just want to know how this would be done using VBA coding. Range2 I already understand and have sorted the code out for. Array formulas for cells H2 and H3 below:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("H2").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(Range2>0, Range2)"
    ActiveSheet.Range("H3").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(Range2<0, Range2)"
    MaxPos = ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Value
    MaxNeg = ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember you need to use the `=CEILING(number, 10)` function combined with the ABS() and a quick check whether the number is negative or not.

For example

[image]

Comment: alright thanks, I'll try this along with another method. Does the formula for B2 (in your example) have the >0 as <0 instead? I am also getting a Type mismatch error when it comes to naming those two 'round up' cells. Could you help with that at all?

Comment: If A1 > 0 then its a positive number you can call the CEILING straight on it. If A1 is less than 0 you need to call ABS() function to treat it as a positive number and then reverse it with the `-` in front of the CEILING. The TypeMismatch error should possibly be a new question as it's definitely not related to the current solution.

Comment: could you type that out as it would look like in the formula? A1 will always be positive because of the MAX IF array I have for that cell. Same with A2 only that one is always negative...

Comment: is the formula bar in the image provided not enough?

Comment: An alternative to me how's formula: `=IF(A1>0,CEILING(A1, 10),FLOOR(A1,10))` . Which you prefer is matter of taste. Ceiling rounds away from 0 if positive and floor rounds away from 0 if negative.